# Trying to compile any haskell program that contains newtypes

Tags: haskell

Whenever I try to compile a haskell program with newtypes, I get an error stating "No instance for *blah blah* arising from the use of ..."  for example:

```
No instance for (Hashable NT.EndPointAddress)
  arising from a use of `hashable-1.2.0.10:Data.Hashable.Class.$gdmhashWithSalt'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Hashable NT.EndPointAddress)
In the expression:
  (hashable-1.2.0.10:Data.Hashable.Class.$gdmhashWithSalt)
In an equation for `hashWithSalt':
    hashWithSalt
      = (hashable-1.2.0.10:Data.Hashable.Class.$gdmhashWithSalt)
In the instance declaration for `Hashable NodeId'
```

Can anyone suggest what might be going on?

Thanks,

Carl

I have added the code relating to the above error message.  It is posted below. The error occurs on line 132.  The code is from Types.hs which is from the development branch of distributed-process posted on github.  I am getting this same error for any code that I try to compile that has newtypes in it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

-- | Types used throughout the Cloud Haskell framework
--
-- We collect all types used internally in a single module because
-- many of these data types are mutually recursive and cannot be split across
-- modules.
module Control.Distributed.Process.Internal.Types
  ( -- * Node and process identifiers
    NodeId(..)
  , LocalProcessId(..)
  , ProcessId(..)
  , Identifier(..)
  , nodeOf
  , firstNonReservedProcessId
  , nullProcessId
    -- * Local nodes and processes
  , LocalNode(..)
  , Tracer(..)
  , LocalNodeState(..)
  , LocalProcess(..)
  , LocalProcessState(..)
  , Process(..)
  , runLocalProcess
  , ImplicitReconnect(..)
    -- * Typed channels
  , LocalSendPortId
  , SendPortId(..)
  , TypedChannel(..)
  , SendPort(..)
  , ReceivePort(..)
    -- * Messages
  , Message(..)
  , isEncoded
  , createMessage
  , createUnencodedMessage
  , unsafeCreateUnencodedMessage
  , messageToPayload
  , payloadToMessage
    -- * Node controller user-visible data types
  , MonitorRef(..)
  , ProcessMonitorNotification(..)
  , NodeMonitorNotification(..)
  , PortMonitorNotification(..)
  , ProcessExitException(..)
  , ProcessLinkException(..)
  , NodeLinkException(..)
  , PortLinkException(..)
  , ProcessRegistrationException(..)
  , DiedReason(..)
  , DidUnmonitor(..)
  , DidUnlinkProcess(..)
  , DidUnlinkNode(..)
  , DidUnlinkPort(..)
  , SpawnRef(..)
  , DidSpawn(..)
  , WhereIsReply(..)
  , RegisterReply(..)
  , ProcessInfo(..)
  , ProcessInfoNone(..)
    -- * Node controller internal data types
  , NCMsg(..)
  , ProcessSignal(..)
    -- * Accessors
  , localProcesses
  , localPidCounter
  , localPidUnique
  , localConnections
  , localProcessWithId
  , localConnectionBetween
  , monitorCounter
  , spawnCounter
  , channelCounter
  , typedChannels
  , typedChannelWithId
    -- * Utilities
  , forever'
  ) where

import System.Mem.Weak (Weak)
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Int (Int32)
import Data.Typeable (Typeable, typeOf)
import Data.Binary (Binary(put, get), putWord8, getWord8, encode)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BSS (ByteString, concat, copy)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
  ( ByteString
  , toChunks
  , splitAt
  , fromChunks
  , length
  )
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal as BSL (ByteString(..))
import Data.Accessor (Accessor, accessor)
import Control.Category ((>>>))
import Control.DeepSeq (NFData(..))
import Control.Exception (Exception)
import Control.Concurrent (ThreadId)
import Control.Concurrent.Chan (Chan)
import Control.Concurrent.STM (STM)
import qualified Network.Transport as NT (EndPoint, EndPointAddress, Connection)
import Control.Applicative (Applicative, Alternative, (<$>), (<*>))
import Control.Monad.Reader (MonadReader(..), ReaderT, runReaderT)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Serializable
  ( Fingerprint
  , Serializable
  , fingerprint
  , encodeFingerprint
  , sizeOfFingerprint
  , decodeFingerprint
  , showFingerprint
  )
import Control.Distributed.Process.Internal.CQueue (CQueue)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Internal.StrictMVar (StrictMVar)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Internal.WeakTQueue (TQueue)
import Control.Distributed.Static (RemoteTable, Closure)
import qualified Control.Distributed.Process.Internal.StrictContainerAccessors as DAC (mapMaybe)

import Data.Hashable
import GHC.Generics

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Node and process identifiers                                               --
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- | Node identifier
newtype NodeId = NodeId { nodeAddress :: NT.EndPointAddress }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Generic)
instance Binary NodeId where
instance NFData NodeId
instance Hashable NodeId where
instance Show NodeId where
  show (NodeId addr) = "nid://" ++ show addr

-- | A local process ID consists of a seed which distinguishes processes from
-- different instances of the same local node and a counter
data LocalProcessId = LocalProcessId
  { lpidUnique  :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int32
  , lpidCounter :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int32
  }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Generic, Show)
```

Comment: Could you post the code that produced this error?

Comment: Did you add instances of the classes you use for the newtype?

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out. EndPointAddress did not have an instance in the master branch of hashable.  I had to download the development branches of the following packages in order to successfully compile distributed-process-platform:

```
hashable
distributed-process
distributed-process-static
rank1dynamic
network-transport
network-transport-tcp
distributed-process-simplelocalnet
distributed-process-platform
```

I found this info in the following thread [compiling distributed-process](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parallel-haskell/jEJIjDXIApI)

Thanks for taking time to answer my post!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple versions of `hashable` installed. Use `ghc-pkg list`, `ghc-pkg unregister`, etc. to figure out what's going on and fix it. Almost certainly you want to only have one version of `hashable`.